# Creating a graph within specific vertex/degree parameters

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that T is a tree with four vertices of degree 3, six vertices of degree 4, one vertex of degree 5, and 8 vertices of degree 6. No other vertices of T have degree 3 or more. How many leaf vertices does T have?

So this seemed simple enough at first; eventually it became abundantly clear that it was not. I assumed that there would be multiple configurations all yielding the same amount of leaves, but I kept adding in extra vertices that disqualified my attempted graphs. Presumably, one would start with the one 5-degree vertex and then go on from there, but it seems like the only way to find a tree that satisfies the listed condition is hidden behind a wall of tedious trial and error.

Is there a property or formula I'm unaware of that'd leave a framework for making such a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You can remove any vertex of degree $2$ from a tree without changing the number of leaves, so you might as well assume that there are no vertices of degree $2$. Then you have $19$ internal vertices whose degrees sum to $89$. Suppose that the tree has $\ell$ leaves and $e$ edges. Then $\ell+19=e+1$, since the graph is a tree. Can you find a second equation relating $\ell$ and $e$? If you get completely stuck, there’s a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse over to see it.

> Handshake lemma.

Comment: I don't think I understand. With what I know of the handshake lemma all I can see is that there should end up an even number of vertices and an odd amount of edges? That would imply that l is odd and e even, but subtracting the one seems to flip the implied parities. I don't see how the number of degrees factors in.

Comment: @Cow: The handshake lemma gives you a very precise relationship between the sum of the degrees of the vertices and the number of edges. The number of edges is $e$. If there are $\ell$ leaves and no vertices of degree $2$, what is the sum of the degrees of all of the vertices?

Comment: I think I've got it now, thank you.

Comment: @Cow: You’re welcome.